# VueJS3: Parsing JSON issue

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm starting with VueJS 3 and I'm trying to render a list of locations stocked in a MongoDataBase. I use axios to manage the request.
The response is good, I can log it in the console, but I can't put it in the Location component.
No errors appears in the browser console and the component doesn't load. When I debug and check Caught Exceptions in VSCode, I have a SyntaxError like this one :

```
Exception has occurred: SyntaxError: Unexpected token    in JSON at position 1
at parse (<anonymous>)
    at has (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:33332:39)
    at has (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:33246:48)
    at runInContext (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:33362:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:34034:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:34067:4)
    at Object.58 (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:34069:4)
    at o (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:28806:374)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:28806:425
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:30565:13)
```

I think I have a problem with parsing the JSON response, but I can't figure where the problem is.
I test the API with Postman and it works fine. I also test it with static datas and it works fine too.
The code of the webComponent :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Location
      v-for="location in locations"
      :key="location.id"
      :locationModel="location"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import { LocationModel } from "../models/LocationModel";
import { useLocationService } from "../composables/LocationService";
import Location from "../components/Location.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "LocationList",

  components: {
    Location
  },

  async setup() {
    const location = useLocationService();
    const locations = ref<Array<LocationModel> | null>(null);
    locations.value = await location.list();
    
    return {
      locations
    };
  }
});
</script>

<style></style>
```

And the code of the LocationService who interact with API :

```
import { LocationModel } from "@/models/LocationModel";
import axios from "axios";

export function useLocationService() {
  return {
    async list(): Promise<Array<LocationModel>> {
      const params = {
        lng: 0.2185714,
        lat: 47.9791214,
        maxDistance: 5000
      };
      const response = await axios.get<Array<LocationModel>>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/locations",
        { params }
      );
      return Promise.resolve(response.data);
    }
  };
}
```

I suppose it's a simple error, but I'm stuck on it since yesterday and I don't know what to do, do you have any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Use `debugger`, `try{}catch(e){}` ;) i bet its the axios response

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returning an object with just a field and not a value.
Why not return the locations.

```
return locations;
```

or

```
return {
 locations : locations
}
```